# Can we do inapp verification via our API, without using IabHelper and base64EncodedPublicKey?

Tags: android, in-app-billing

The in-app billing library has a method `verifyPurchase()` in the `Security` class. In version 2 of this library the `base64EncodedPublicKey` was located inside `Security` class so we basically did not use it ever, but did verification via our API and then returned `true/false` as if the verification was done by in-app library.

In version 3, `base64EncodedPublicKey` is not located inside `Security` class any more, but we keep it in the `Main` class and pass it as a parameter to `IabHelper` object which then calls `verifyPurchase()` in the `Security`  and passes 3 parameters now (instead of 2 as in version 2).

Is now mandatory that `IabHelper` does the verification? Can we still omit it like before and do verification via our API?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`IabHelper` is just a wrapper around In-app Billing V3 API. It's designed to make things easier. You don't have to use it, so it's not mandatory to perform verification using `IabHelper`.

Comment: So doing verification via `base64EncodedPublicKey` is not needed at all?

Comment: It depends on your use case. If you have backend you should verify purchases on your backend and you don't need to verify it on the device. Otherwise the only option is to verify purchase on the device directly so the public key is one of the key element to verify a purchase.